# Proving generating system for $U:=\{(a,b,c,d)|a+b+c+d=0)\},U\subseteq \mathbb{C}^4=:V,V\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have already proved it  if V would be a $\mathbb{C}$ vectorspace. I picked  $(1,-1,0,0);(0,1,-1,0);(0,0,1,-1)$ as my base showed linear Independence and said if there would exist one more basevector the Dimension would be 4 which cannot be because then it would be $\mathbb{C}$, which would mean $(1,0,0,0)$ would also be in $U$ which is false. I cannot make the same Argument with $\mathbb{R}$, my corresponding base would be $(i,-i,0,0);(0,i,-i,0);(0,0,i,-i);(1,-1,0,0);(0,1,-1,0);(0,0,1,-1)$

of Dimension 6. The Base for V would be of Dimension $8$. how can I now prove that my new base is a generating System?

Comment: Indeed, U is an R-vector subspace of dimension 6, of the R-vector space U=C^4 of dimension 8. What is your question?

Comment: How can I prove that my suggested base is a generating System of $U$? So that I get every Vector of the form $(a,b,c,d)|a+b+c+d=0$ So far I have just assumed that the Dimension of U is 6 and suggested the base $ (i,-i,0,0);(0,i,-i,0);(0,0,i,-i);(1,-1,0,0);(0,1,-1,0);(0,0,1,-1)$. But I have not proved that it is indeed a generating system

Comment: Well, $a+b+c+d=0$ iff $\Re(a+b+c+d)=0$ and $\Im(a+b+c+d)=0$. Now,  $\Re(a+b+c+d)=\Re(a)+\Re(b)+\Re(c)+\Re(d)$ and $\Im(a+b+c+d)=\Im(a)+\Im(b)+\Im(c)+\Im(d)$ hence...

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention." Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same  way as  you already did  when $\mathbb{C}^4$  was considered as $\mathbb{C}$-vectorspace and as indicated in the comment by @Did, we show that
\begin{align*}
G=\{&(1,-1,0,0),(0,1,-1,0),(0,0,1,-1),\\
&(i,-i,0,0),(0,i,-i,0),(0,0,i,-i)\}
\end{align*}
is a generating system of $U$:
\begin{align*}
U:=\{(a,b,c,d)|a+b+c+d=0)\},U\subseteq \mathbb{C}^4
\end{align*}
when $\mathbb{C}^4$ is considered as $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace.

> Let $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{U}$,
>   Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> &\Re(a)(1,-1,0,0)+\Im(a)(i,-i,0,0)\\
> &\qquad+\Re(a+b)(0,1,-1,0)+\Im(a+b)(0,i,-i,0)\\
> &\qquad+\Re(a+b+c)(0,0,1,-1)+\Im(a+b+c)(0,0,i,-i)\\
> &\quad=(a,-a,0,0)+(0,a+b,-a-b,0)+(0,0,a+b+c,-a-b-c)\\
> &\quad=(a,b,c,-a-b-c)\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=(a,b,c,d)}
> \end{align*} 
>   we conclude the set $G$ is a generating system of $U$.

Comment: @RM777: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty.